# issue with func in matplotlib.FuncAnimation not updating data

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
ax.set_zlim([0, 90]) 

x = np.linspace(xL, xR, nx)
z = np.linspace(zL, zR, nz)
X, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)
r = T[:,5,:,0]

graph = ax.plot_surface(X, Z, r)

def update_graph(q):
    r = T[:,5,:,q]
    graph.set_3d_properties(r)
    return graph

ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, update_graph, frames = 11)
plt.show()
```

I have the code above, T is a 100x100x100x12 matrix, and I want to make an animation showing a surface plot as the 4th axis goes from 0-11. However it seems that the animation portion is not working  correctly, and I believe the issue is in my update_graph function that it is not passing back an updated value of r to be used in the plot.

Comment: Try adding a comma at the end of `return graph`. That way the function returns a tuple (with one element) instead of a single value.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that for `Poly3DCollection` [`set_3d_properties()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.html#Poly3DCollection.set_3d_properties) is only implemented as the following

> ```
> def set_3d_properties(self):
>     # Force the collection to initialize the face and edgecolors
>     # just in case it is a scalarmappable with a colormap.
>     self.update_scalarmappable()
>     self._sort_zpos = None
>     self.set_zsort('average')
>     self._facecolors3d = PolyCollection.get_facecolor(self)
>     self._edgecolors3d = PolyCollection.get_edgecolor(self)
>     self._alpha3d = PolyCollection.get_alpha(self)
>     self.stale = True
> ```

So it doesn't actually modify the data as it does with other 3d objects (e.g. [`Line3D`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/art3d.html#Line3D.set_3d_properties)).

Instead, I would recommend you do something like this

```py
graph = ax.plot_surface(X, Z, r)

def update_graph(q):
    r = T[:,5,:,q]
    plt.cla()
    ax.set_xlim([0, 1])
    ax.set_ylim([0, 1])
    ax.set_zlim([0, 90]) 
    graph = ax.plot_surface(X, Z, r)
    return graph,
```

Obviously it is a bit tedious to reset all the axis properties on each update but I don't think there is any easier way.

Also note the trailing comma in `return graph,` - this is necessary when `blit=True` because `FuncAnimation` expects an iterable of artists to be returned. However, the return statement is ignored when `blit=False`.

Here is the result of a simple example using this approach

[image]